# How to display simulation result from Dymola in LabVIEW environment?

Tags: interface, labview, dymola, coupling

I would like to simulate a radial fan test rig in `Dymola`.

The test rig itself acquire the data from several sensors using `LabVIEW`.

My planning is to compare the simulation result from `Dymola` and the data from sensors in real time in `LabVIEW` environment.

In the same time also I want to variate the system by changing rotational speed and opening valve while the test rig is running.

Are there any possibilities to do so?

I attached a figure of the schematic of test rig here.

[image]

Comment: This should certainly be possible but as it stands your question is much too broad for this site. If you try something and hit a specific problem, come back here with a specific question showing what you tried and what the problem is. If you don't know where to start, I suggest you try the forums on ni.com or accessing technical support or training from National Instruments.

Comment: Thanks for the comment...actually I'm not so familiar with this stuff but from some sources, it said that I have to export the dymola model into FMU (functional mock up unit) file extension as the first step and then import it into LabVIEW. The problem is I dont know yet how can I import the model into LabVIEW. Is there anyone here can give me an idea?

Comment: If you actually want to run the model in real-time you're into the domain of hardware-in-loop simulation which needs additional processing hardware and additional software besides LabVIEW. However for your purposes couldn't you just run the simulation first and save both the stimulus and output signals, then load that data into LabVIEW and 'replay' it, outputting the stimulus to the real hardware and comparing the measured to the simulated response?

Comment: hmm..Actually, we would like to apply digital twin concept for the test rig, this is why we need to run the model in real time. As it is the beginning of the project, so I try to collect any information that can support the idea.

Comment: Last couple days ago I tried to export a simple model from Dymola into FMU but I got a problem with importing it in LabVIEW. For importing fmu in labVIEW I just follow the instruction from NI group (https://forums.ni.com/t5/NI-Labs-Toolkits/LabVIEW-support-for-FMI-for-Model-Exchange/ta-p/3506018). 
The problem is as already mentioned by the other guys in the group discussion, I could not display the input and output terminal. Is there any other way to resolve the problem?

Comment: OK, this is outside my experience and I don't think you'll have much luck with this question on Stack Overflow, sorry. It looks to me as if the toolkit you linked to is still in development rather than an officially released product so it may be that it simply doesn't work for what you want to do yet. It looks as if the [Control Design and Simulation toolkit](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/11281/en/) is mainly designed for use with Simulink, do you have access to that and could you maybe develop the real-time simulation part of the concept there first? I believe Simulink can now import FMUs.

Comment: Alternatively it looks as if you might be able to [do what you want using NI VeriStand](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/14299/en/) alongside LabVIEW, but that may be more complex and expensive than you were after...

Comment: yes..probably the toolkit is still in development condition. I will check Simulink and other alternatives, NI VeriStand that u mentioned here. Hopefully, I can find a way to implement my project. Thanks again for the suggestions. Based on this comment also I can advance my idea to get the solution.